# Ajax. return false\true

Tags: javascript, ajax

Подскажите пожалуйста. Есть вот такой запрос

```js
     jQuery.ajax({
          url: 'event/add_event',
          type: 'POST',
          data: formData,
          contentType: false,
          processData: false,
          beforeSend: function () {
            jQuery('#ajaxmessage').html('<img src="<?php echo $this->config->item('img_folder');?>wait.gif"/>');
          },
          success: function(msg) {
          if (msg === "ok")
            jQuery('#ajaxmessage').html('<div class="alert alert-success text-center">Мероприятие добавлено</div>');
          else
            jQuery('#ajaxmessage').html('<div class="alert alert-danger">' + msg + '</div>');
          }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

В контроллере идет обработка и он возвращает true/false . как красиво обработать во вьюшке это ? а то сейчас echo "ok"; транслировать ну как то очень костыльно. Спасибо

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Отдавайте с сервера JSON-объект:

```
{
   "status": true
}
```

А при ошибке что-нибудь такое:

```
{
   "status": false,
   "reason": "Для добавления мероприятия вы должны быть авторизованы"
}
```

Также можно использовать [коды состояния HTTP](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_HTTP). При успешном ответе отдавайте 2** код ответа, например, `200` (OK). Таким образом выполнится событие AJAX `success`, а при ошибке - 4**-5** коды. В таком случае сработает событие AJAX `error`.

Comment: Спасибо вам за ответ. И за пример так же спасибо. Подскажите если не трудно, обрабатывать в ajax коды ведь не нужно ? он сам понимает что 2** это success, а error на 5** ?

Comment: Еще момент в AJAX ответ JSON надо преобразовывать или он сам понимает ?

Comment: @ДмитрийБережной, укажите в AJAX параметр "dataType", дав ему значение "json", и тогда он будет преобразовываться в объект автоматически. А если с сервера придет невалидный JSON, то сработает событие "error".

Comment: @ДмитрийБережной, по поводу кодов: да, вы все правильно поняли.

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное .

Comment: @ДмитрийБережной, если мой ответ вам помог, вы можете отметить его галочкой слева как решение.